# Can't connect Philips Hue Bridge with network

Tags: philips-hue, bridge

I have installed the Philips Hue Light Starter Kit (Bridge + 2 White Lamps). Yesterday this worked well and I could control it via App or Alexa. Today the Hue Bridge disconnected from network and I'm not able to reconnect it. I restarted my Fritzbox-Router, I turned off/on the lamps manually and I restarted the Bridge. I changed the Ethernet-Cable and LAN-Port on the Router. No way to get a connection.

The Hue Bridge shows power-lamp on but ethernet and Internet lamps are off. Hue App tells me there is no connection as well. I also can't see the Bridge on my FritzBox. Someone has an Idea?

Comment: Is there a factory reset on the Hue Bridge?

Comment: @Helmar There is a small hole, which is marked with "factory reset". But if I use a pin to push it, there is nothing. The pin just disappear inside the hole. There doesn't seem to be a button... not sure if this is right.

Comment: Ok the "factory reset" button is just inside a deep whole. I found it now, but this Button is also without any effect.

Comment: Did it solve your problem?

Comment: Finally I called the Hue Service and they told me to replace the starterkit with a new one. So I will send it back and get a new one. Hope this will work...

Answer (score 1):

To improve discoverability, making an answer from a comment by the OP from 6 years ago:

> Finally I called the Hue Service and they told me to replace the starter kit with a new one. So I will send it back and get a new one. Hope this will work...
> *--SebiDec 29, 2017 at 20:44*

Answer (score 0):

There are a few steps you can try to troubleshoot the issue with your Philips Hue Bridge disconnecting from your network:

1. Try resetting the bridge by holding down the button on the back of
   the bridge for 15 seconds. Then, release the button and wait for the
   bridge to restart.
2. Make sure the bridge is properly connected to your router via an
   Ethernet cable and that the cable is in good working condition.
3. Check to make sure that the bridge is using the correct IP address,
   subnet mask, and gateway settings for your network.
4. Try disabling and re-enabling the DHCP server on your router.
5. Check to see if there is a firmware update available for your bridge
   and update it if necessary.
6. If the issue persists, check the Philips Hue website for further
   troubleshooting tips or contact their customer support.

It's also a good idea to check that your router is functioning properly, especially if you have other devices connected to the router that are working fine.